# How unlink variable's values from the possibles changes of a parent variable?

Tags: python

I need that the values of some varible doesn't change when I change the parent variable.

```py
import numpy as np
# Defining the parent variable
A = np.zeros((5,5)) 
print(A)
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
# Asing values a the new variable
B = A[:2,:2]
print (B)
array([[0., 0.],
       [0., 0.]])
# Change the parent variable
A[:,1] = 1
print(A)
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.]])
# The variable values change whit the parent variable
print(B)
array([[0., 1.],
       [0., 1.]])
```

I expect not changes in the values of the B, but this changes show some linking with the A values. How I can avoid this linking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As J. Blackadar stated using .copy() will be you're friend.

By using copy you are creating another allocation in memory rather than pointing to same location with two variables.

Not using .copy() :

```
a = 5 
b= a
b = b-2
print(a) - > 3
```

Using .copy() :

```
a = 5 
b= a.copy()
b = b-2
print(a) - > 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [copy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html) to make a copy of the array in memory.